# Multiplying an element in an array with another array which is raised to a power

Tags: python, for-loop

Given two lists:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
```

I want to multiply each element in y by x, the elements in x are raised to a power according to the order of the element in y.

For example the first element in y is 1 and its order is 0th. Each element in x is then raised to the power of 0, then multiplied by the element which is 1.
The second element in y is 2 and its order is 1st. Each element in x is raised to the power of 1, then multiplied by the element which is 2, etc.
I have tried the following code:

```
B=[]
C=[]

for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
         b=y[i]*x[j]**i
         B.append(b)
    C.append(B)
print(C)
```

However it gave:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 12, 27], [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 12, 27], [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 12, 27]]
```

rather than:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 6], [3, 12, 27]]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner version that uses list comprehensions:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]
print [[vy * (vx**iy) for ix, vx in enumerate(x)] for iy, vy in enumerate(y)]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 6], [3, 12, 27]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem:

```
C=[]

x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,2,3]

for i in range(0, len(y)):
    B = list()
    for j in range(0, len(x)):
        b=y[i]*(x[j]**i)
        B.append(b)
    C.append(B)
print C
```

This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the (now fixed) indentation problem, you must re-initialize B in every iteration of the outer loop. Also, append B[:], not B. This way you make copies every time instead of appending the very same list over and over.

Lists in python behave in a bit different manner than strings or integers. For example, if you execute this code:

```
A=[2]
B=A
A.append(3)
print(B)
```

It will print out [2,3].
If you write `B=A[:]`, python will make a copy of the A list and the output will be just [2].